# Zywall USG 100 - How connect to modem interface?

Tags: authentication

I have an Zywall USG 100.

My modem have this ip: 192.168.1.100 and is connected into WAN1 port on the Zywall.
The Zywall have this ip: 192.168.1.1

I used the "quick configuration setup", and all computer on the network go in internet without problems.

But I can't access to my modem web interface.

What I need to change in the configuration of the firewall ?

Thank you

Comment: if your 'modem' has that IP address, it's not just a modem, it's a router too. Chances are both devices are now doing NAT & both trying to do DHCP. That would be first place to start.

Comment: to get to the modem interface you'll have to take the new router out & connect directly - then you ought to investigate how to switch off the routing functionality of one or the other. 2 routers in a row is not good news.

Comment: but, the ip can stay like this ? Or I need to change ? And, in the zywall I need first to create an "object > address" and after a "routing" option ? Thank you